# Filter a model within a range of IDs with Ember.JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have store that contains all of the images that the user has uploaded over time. When they upload a new group of images I receive each image's ID from the uploader. They are then moved to a new route where they need to update those newly uploaded images with meta data. I would like to use the previous store but filter out everything except the images they have uploaded.

So the question is... How do I filter a store by only a range of ids. For example, if my uploader returns [30, 31, 32]. I would like the view to only display those images.

I think the router should have a filter property like this but I'm not sure.

```
App.PhotosDetailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend( {
  model: function(params) {
     return this.get('content').filterBy('id', id >= params[0] );
  }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the filter function, I'm not positive what content is in this case, but this is how you use filter

```
model: function(params) {
  this.store.find('photos');
  return this.store.filter('photos', function(item){
    return item.get('id') >= 10; // dummy parameter
  });
}
```

Comment: When I use this.get('content') I receive the error "Cannot call method 'filter' of undefined". I'm using Ember Data 1.0.beta.1. So I tried using store since it hadn't yet made a request to the endpoint. I ultimately receive a boolean value instead of pushing the object data into the model. Any idea how I could do this differently? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iveZuPax/3/edit

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know what content was either, I just saw you had it in your model hook and figured you must have been assigning it somewhere else (such as beforeModel hook or something).  If you're using the store you can call filter with a model type and a function and it will return you a live record array (meaning it will update as new records make it into the system).  `filter` doesn't fetch data from the server though, so in that case you'll have needed to call find at some point (in the example above I call it right before).